# [NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource returns nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to connect my app to SQLite database but I get messages that tell me that the database is created but there are no tables.

I debugged the program and discovered that
`[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource]` always returns `nil`

```
NSString* file = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:_databaseName ofType:_databaseType];
```

Why is this happening?
Please help me!

Comment: Type is a string representing file extension (e.g., @"png" or @"txt"). Did you log both strings? (Name and type)

Comment: Also, name usually is the filename without extension (not sure if including the extension causes error or not). Open resource file's info panel and make sure the extension is not mixed with the file name (e.g.: "MyImage.png.png" with extension set to "hidden")

Answer (score 1):

First : make sure your database is in the app bundle.

Then you need to implement methods to copy the path to the documentary Directory .as these

```
-(NSString *) getDBPath:(NSString*)databaseName {
// search for the existed paths
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(  NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
```

}

```
- (void) InstantiateYourDatabase:(NSString *)DatabaseName {


//Using NSFileManager we can perform many file system operations.

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSError *error;
NSString *dpname=DatabaseName;

_dbPath = [self getDBPath:dpname];

BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:_dbPath];

NSLog(@"success == %i",success);

if( !success) {

    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] 
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:DatabaseName];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:_dbPath error:&error];

}
```

}

Tell me if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

try below code for find database path

```
    NSString *databaseName = @"your_db_name.sql";
    NSString *databasePath;
    // Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    NSLog(@"Database Path is: %@",databasePath);
```

You want More Detail about Sqllite Database Connectivity in iOS try this [tutorial](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/)

Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you created a sqlite db file and drag it to your project in xcode3, it's in application document folder while its running.

```
NSString *databaseName = @"cartoon.db";
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
```

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you are using the database you have to use the Documents Directory